# How do I render a Company after 5 Products? | React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I'm trying to make a ecommerce store and I want to render a `<CompanyCard/>` component after every 2 `<ProductCard/>` components.
I've never done anything like this so I'm not sure if I'm doing the right approach

Here is a example of what I want:

```
<ProductCard/>
<ProductCard/>
<CompanyCard/>
<ProductCard/>
<ProductCard/>
<CompanyCard/>
(and so on..)
```

but for some reason im getting a blank page with these 2 errors in the console

```
The above error occurred in the <CompanyCard> component:
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')
```

This is my code (I'm also using React Redux)

```
function HomePage() {
  let counter = 0;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { error, loading, products } = productList;

  const companyList = useSelector((state) => state.companyList);
  const { companies } = companyList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts(), listCompanies());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="homePage">
        <div className="centerItemsContainer">
          <div className="productsContainer">
            {products.map((product) => {
              counter++;

              if (counter % 4 === 0) {
                const companyIndex = counter / 4 - 1;
                const company = companies[companyIndex];

                return (
                  <>
                    <CompanyCard company={company} />
                    <ProductCard product={product} />
                  </>
                );
              } else {
                return <ProductCard product={product} />;
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Every two or after five?

Comment: Are the company cards related to the preceding products or is it just random? If they are related how are you determining the merge process since they're in two different states/arrays?

Comment: I think you're on the right track with modulus, but it looks like you've got an error in your CompanyCard component. What happens if you replace that with just an HTML element? Also, look up `map`. You can use it's counter instead of your own.

Comment: @Konrad in my code its supposed to be 5 but I wrote above 2 so that it would be easier to show a example

Comment: @net.uk.sweet if i replace <CompanyCard/> with a <div>Text Here</div> it does render on the page, but for some reason the page doesnt render if <CompanyCard/> isnt commented out

Comment: If you added examples of your datasets to your question we'd have a much better idea of how you're approaching this. Referring to my previous comment are the sets of data linked in any way, or are you just adding random companies after every set of products?

Comment: The page doesn't render because an error is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error, because your iterator exceeds array length

I would rather use a normal for loop for this:

```js
const products1 = [...Array(10).keys()].map((e) => "p" + e);
const companies1 = [...Array(10).keys()].map((e) => "c" + e);

console.log(getList(products1, companies1));

const products2 = [...Array(10).keys()].map((e) => "p" + e);
const companies2 = [...Array(1).keys()].map((e) => "c" + e);

console.log(getList(products2, companies2));

function getList(products, companies) {
  const list = [];
  const min = Math.min(products.length, companies.length);
  for (
    let i = 0, p = 0, c = 0;
    i < products.length + companies.length;
    i += 1
  ) {
    // every fifth is a company, but only if there is a company left
    // or there are no more products
    if ((c < companies.length && i % 5 === 4) || p >= products.length) {
      list.push(companies[c++]);
    } else {
      list.push(products[p++]);
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```

Final component:

```
function HomePage() {
  let counter = 0;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { error, loading, products } = productList;

  const companyList = useSelector((state) => state.companyList);
  const { companies } = companyList;

  function getList() {
    const list = [];
    const min = Math.min(products.length, companies.length);
    for (
      let i = 0, p = 0, c = 0;
      i < products.length + companies.length;
      i += 1
    ) {
      if ((c < companies.length && i % 5 === 4) || p >= products.length) {
        list.push(<CompanyCard company={companies[c++]} />);
      } else {
        list.push(<ProductCard product={products[p++]} />);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts(), listCompanies());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="homePage">
        <div className="centerItemsContainer">
          <div className="productsContainer">{getList()}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems like you are simply selecting a company that does not exist.  Log `companyIndex`  and see what values you are using.

Also, there is no need to manually keep track of `counter`, it is the second argument from `map`, so just write:

```
        {products.map((product, counter) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps if u want to render company on 4 th place pls change it to 4 same goes for what place u want

```
   const products = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {products.map((product, index) => {
        const counter = index + 1;
        if (counter % 2 === 0) {
          return (
            <>
              <p>Prod{index}</p>
              <p>Company</p>
            </>
          );
        }
        return <p>Prod{index}</p>;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{products.map((item, index) => (
  <>
    <ProductCard />
    {(!!index && !((index + 1) % 5) && <CompanyCard />)}
  </>
)}
```

Comment: Code dumps are rarely useful without some sort of explanatory note/comments.